# How do I achieve this grid and tab structure in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the following grid and tab structure in a Shiny app.

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UccQT.png)

What I want to get to is to have a different tabsetPanel for every Dataset that I choose in the left column.

So basically I would have a "master" left column - that could be hidden if the user wants so - and a central panel with different tabs for whichever dataset one selects on the left column.

This is the current code:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(gridlayout)
library(bslib)

ui <- grid_page(
  layout = c(
    "header  header",
    "sidebar Impost"
  ),
  row_sizes = c(
    "40px",
    "1fr"
  ),
  col_sizes = c(
    "165px",
    "1fr"
  ),
  gap_size = "1rem",
  grid_card(
    area = "sidebar",
    card_header("DATASET Simulator"),
    card_body(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "dataset",
        label = "DATASET",
        choices = list(
          "Dataset 1" = "Dataset 1",
          "Dataset 2" = "Dataset 2",
          "Dataset 3" = "Dataset 3"
        ),
        selected = "Dataset 1",
        width = "100%"
      ),
      em("Select the type of dataset you want to simulate.")
    )
  ),
  grid_card_text(
    area = "header",
    content = "Dataset Simulation Project",
    alignment = "start",
    is_title = FALSE
  ),
  grid_card(
    area = "Impost",
    full_screen = TRUE,
    card_header("Dataset 1"),
    card_body(
      tabsetPanel(
        nav_panel(title = "Parameters"),
        nav_panel(title = "Results 1"),
        nav_panel(title = "Results 2")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have checked the Mastering Shiny book, lots of internet sources, and used the new Shiny UI Editor but I am at a loss on how to achieve it.

Comment: Have you looked into using shinydashboardplus and it's rightSidebar() function? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinydashboardPlus/versions/0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to both YBS and Gonzalo T F. Finally I mixed your answers to create the following body through shinydashboard and conditional panels:

```
dashboardBody(
#dataset 1
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.dataset == 'dataset1'",
                 card_header('Data 1') %>% h2,
                 card_body(
                   tabsetPanel(
                     id = "tabs1",
                     type = c("tabs"),
                     nav_panel(title = "P 1"),
                     nav_panel(title = "R 1"),
                     nav_panel(title = "G 1")
                     )
                   )
                 ),
#dataset 2
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.dataset == 'dataset2'",
                 card_header('Data 2') %>% h2,
                 card_body(
                   tabsetPanel(
                     id = "tabs1",
                     type = c("tabs"),
                     nav_panel(title = "P 2"),
                     nav_panel(title = "R 2"),
                     nav_panel(title = "G 2")
                     )
                   )
                 )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Shinydashboard](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/index.html) allows you to easily create such a structure.

I hope this works.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dataset Simulation Project"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    h3("Dataset Simulator"),
    selectInput("dataset", label = h3("DATASET"), 
                choices = list( "Dataset 1" = "Dataset 1",
                                "Dataset 2" = "Dataset 2",
                                "Dataset 3" = "Dataset 3"), 
                selected = 1)
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    h2(uiOutput("selectedValue")),
    tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                tabPanel("Parameters", plotOutput("plot")),
                tabPanel("Results 1", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
                tabPanel("Results 2", tableOutput("table"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # You can access the value of the widget with input$select, e.g.
  output$selectedValue <-   renderUI({
    selected_option <- input$dataset
    h2(selected_option)})
    }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This only changes the header, though, and I wanted to change the whole panel as the response from YBS does. The UI looks pretty good with the shinydashboard, nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `conditionalPanel()` to obtain the desired output.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(gridlayout)
library(bslib)

ui <- grid_page(
  layout = c(
    "header  header",
    "sidebar Impost"
  ),
  row_sizes = c(
    "40px",
    "1fr"
  ),
  col_sizes = c(
    "165px",
    "1fr"
  ),
  gap_size = "1rem",
  grid_card(
    area = "sidebar",
    card_header("DATASET Simulator"),
    card_body(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "dataset",
        label = "DATASET",
        choices = list(
          "Dataset 1" = "Dataset 1",
          "Dataset 2" = "Dataset 2",
          "Dataset 3" = "Dataset 3"
        ),
        selected = "Dataset 1",
        width = "100%"
      ),
      em("Select the type of dataset you want to simulate.")
    )
  ),
  grid_card_text(
    area = "header",
    content = "Dataset Simulation Project",
    alignment = "start",
    is_title = FALSE
  ),
  grid_card(
    area = "Impost",
    full_screen = TRUE,
    #card_header("Dataset 1"),
    card_header(conditionalPanel( condition = "input.dataset == 'Dataset 1'", "Dataset 1"),
                conditionalPanel( condition = "input.dataset == 'Dataset 2'", "Dataset 2"),
                conditionalPanel( condition = "input.dataset == 'Dataset 3'", "Dataset 3")
                ),
    card_body(
      conditionalPanel( condition = "input.dataset == 'Dataset 1'", 
                        tabsetPanel(id = "tabs1", type = c("tabs"), 
                                    nav_panel(title = "Parameters"),
                                    nav_panel(title = "Results 1"),
                                    nav_panel(title = "Results 2")
                        )
      ),
      conditionalPanel( condition = "input.dataset == 'Dataset 2'",
                        tabsetPanel(id = "tabs2", type = c("tabs"),
                                    nav_panel(title = "Parameters2"),
                                    nav_panel(title = "Results 21"),
                                    nav_panel(title = "Results 22")
                        )
      )
    )
  ) 
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

It is true that you can use `shinydashboard` to achieve the same by using `tabBox` feature.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.
I don't think the upvote is showing as I need more reputation to cast it.